# CSS and HTML input attribute defaults

Tags: html, css, html-input

I am trying to set the minimum and maximum default values for an input field.  I can set the color fine, but the min and max attributes seem to have no effect.  Is there any way to have the minimum and maximum values be set through CSS? Code is below, thanks in advance!

```
<html>
<head>
<title>IP Calculator</title>
<style>
input[type="number"]{
    min:0;
    max:255;
    color:green;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>

<input type="number" name="test">

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there any way to have the minimum and maximum values be set through CSS?

No. CSS is a style sheet language. It describes the presentation of data, not the rules for what the data can be.

You should use HTML attributes for this.

Comment: Thank you. My understanding of CSS is limited, thanks for help!

Answer (score 2):

You are barking up the wrong tree trying to do this with CSS. HTML5 offers a structure like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

input[type="number"]{color:green;}

</style>
</head>
<body>

<input type="number" min="0" max="255" step="1" value="50" name="test">

</body>
</html>
```